# How can I fetch poster of a movie from TMDB in android. I have API key. Code I have tried:

Tags: android, rest, api, key, movie

The code is not giving any output:

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

```
    URL url = new URL("http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/550?api_key=fb7bb23f03b6994dafc674c074d01761");
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    con.setDoOutput(true);
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");

    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader((con.getInputStream())));

    String output;
    System.out.println("Output from Server .... \n");
    while ((output = br.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(output);

    }

}
```

Comment: What do you mean not giving output . I have tried same and getting this as Output `Output from Server .... 

{"adult":false,"backdrop_path":"/87hTDiay2N2qWyX4Ds7ybXi9h8I.jpg","belongs_to_collection":null,"budget":63000000,"genres":[{"id":18,"name":"Drama"}],"homepage":"http://www.foxmovies.com/movies/fight-club","id":550,"imdb_id":"tt0137523","original_language":"en","original_title":"Fight Club","overview":"A ticking-time-bomb insomniac and a ..` and so on

Comment: I checked in Android Monitor.. but unable to see this output there. Where should I find this?